# What Difference between ofType and javaType in mapping in myBatis

Tags: mybatis

Could please some one clarify me the situation where i have to use ofType and javaType in mappings xml file in mybatis.
And explain difference between them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`javaType` is the type of the currently mapped property.
`ofType` is the type of elements in the collection, it is used only  in `<collection>`

[The documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) states:

```
<collection property="posts" javaType="ArrayList" column="id" ofType="Post" select="selectPostsForBlog"/>
```

> Read as: "A collection of posts in an ArrayList of type Post."